# How to prevent CCLabelBMFont from updating position?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Every time I change `.string` property of my `CCLabelBMFont` object, the position is updated. So if I want to show updating lapsed time, then time is changing position on each update.

How can I maintain position of `CCLabelBMFont` while changing string value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the position of the node should remain the same till you change it somehow. I suppose you mean that text position is related to its length. Try to set anchor point of the label. If anchor point set to 0,0 (left bottom corner) then when text length will grow its position will remain the same.

P.S. you can use different anchor point values to achieve alignment that you need

Comment: It remain on fixed position only if horizontal anchor is set to `0`. How to achieve same when h-anchor is `1`? I need that in order to right align my label.

Comment: @Pablo if your anchor point is set to 0,1 then it should behave as normal text in the text editor. It should expand from left to right and from top to bottom. Top left corner positon should remain the same

Comment: Right, but I need top right position remain same. So I set it to 1,1 for instance and position of label is drifting.

Comment: @JohnPoisin: yes. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReETey9AhFg&feature=youtube_gdata

Comment: @Pablo you should set anchor point 0,1 or use monospace font, otherwise your label will drift because letters have different width. I guess it's not a problem to use align by left corner

Comment: Not a problem in the example I gave, but problem for other cases. If you anchor left side, it should also drift, because the letters are again not monospace. I want to understand what's the difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38967/discussion-between-johnpoison-and-pablo)